# should I write “These details belongs to my dad” or “These are my dad's details ” when writing an email?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

When writing an email should I write ***"These details belongs to my dad"*** or ***"These are my dad's details"***? I know this sounds somewhat silly but I want to be grammatically correct.

Comment: This is the comment I provided to the [same question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/505401/should-i-write-these-details-belongs-to-my-dad-or-these-are-my-dads-details) that was asked at EL&U: "Both sentences *could* [mean] the same thing. (Although it should be *belong*.) It depends on what you mean. If *details* means *contact information*, then the second sentence is much better. (Despite the fact that the most idiomatic would simply be *this **is** my dad's contact information.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct and it's up to you what you choose to use.

I personally would feel more comfortable with the second option, i.e. "These are my dad's details"